# asyncio.create_subprocess_shell didn't work in aiohttp server handler function

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to excute a cmd in aiohttp handler function, but asyncio.create_subprocess_shell does not work in handler function. The following are some codes.

code 1: does not work in aiohttp handler function, error information is "jobID = int(x[-1]), index out of range".

```
cmd = "sbatch some.sh"
proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
    cmd, 
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
)
stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
x = stdout.decode().split()
jobID = int(x[-1])
```

code 2: "work well" in aiohttp handler function.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["sbatch", "some.sh"], shell=True)
x = output.decode().split()
jobID = int(x[-1])
```

However, code 2 is not asynchronous.

code 3: work well in python terminal.

```
import asyncio
async def main():
    cmd = "sbatch some.sh"
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        cmd, 
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    x = stdout.decode().split()
    jobID = int(x[-1])
    print(jobID)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I just don't know why that asyncio.create_subprocess_shell didn't work in aiohttp server handler function. Any Suggestions?
Thanks in advance.